# It's a waste of time [maintaining-code]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Since maintaining code is such a large portion of a software developer's life, maybe it's not surprising that there is a [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) tag. However, it's a meta-tag, and none of the questions I've found would suffer from losing it.

- No tag wiki
- 16 questions (1 already closed)

This tag doesn't merit full burnination (ala [Shog's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)), but some community input would be appreciated, as I propose to kill the tag off.

Other similar tags to be considered:

- [maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) x 379, 47 asked this year, *The concept of keeping software or hardware functional in a productive environment*, no wiki
- [maintenance-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-mode) × 45, 11 asked this year, no wiki
- [code-maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-maintainability) × 40, 10 asked this year, no wiki
- [maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintainability) × 203, 19 asked this year, *Maintainability refers to the nature, methods, theory and art of maximizing the ease with which an asset may be sustained, modified or enhanced throughout the duration of its expected useful life.*, no wiki
- [maintenance-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-plan) × 56, 6 asked this year, *A Maintenance plan is any variety of scheduled maintenance to an object or item of equipment.
  In SQL Server a maintenance plan creates a workflow of the tasks required to make sure that the database is optimized, regularly backed up and free of inconsistencies.*

  For the most part, these are SQL related, but there are a number of other questions that indicate that the tag may be ambiguous. A cleanup may be enough, especially of off-topic questions; what do you think?

  - [What is an ideal way to put a Java Web Application (Struts) into Maintenace mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681664/what-is-an-ideal-way-to-put-a-java-web-application-struts-into-maintenace-mode)
  - [Only one Storyboard for iPad and iPod/iPhone devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926863/only-one-storyboard-for-ipad-and-ipod-iphone-devices)
  - [Display website maintenance notification few hours before the maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635016/display-website-maintenance-notification-few-hours-before-the-maintenance)
  - [How to implement custom maintenance pages on multiple Amazon instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112920/how-to-implement-custom-maintenance-pages-on-multiple-amazon-instances)
  - [What is your ratio Bug fixing vs Enhancements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354482/what-is-your-ratio-bug-fixing-vs-enhancements) (closed)
  - [Keep a TFS source backup in Visual Source Safe. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912745/keep-a-tfs-source-backup-in-visual-source-safe-possible)
  - [Maintaining a Caching Appliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843750/maintaining-a-caching-appliance)
  - [What is a good early termination fee for maintenance contracts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603597/what-is-a-good-early-termination-fee-for-maintenance-contracts)

Comment: "Maintaining code is such a large portion of a software developer's life..." and "it's a waste of time", this title pun makes me sad.

Comment: @approxiblue I tried more positive puns, but they didn't work. Maybe "Everyone hates [maintaining-code]" or "No more [maintaining-code]"?

Comment: I'd agree. There are more specific practices covered by "maintaining code" that are more focused and useful, like refactoring, debuggers, unit - tests and so on.

Comment: @TimBarrass Tags for refactoring you say... I'd expect a separate burnination post for that.

Comment: [tag:maintainability] is not a meta tag

Comment: @approxiblue: Questions about tools used by programmers that solve problems unique to software development are on-topic, [tag:refactoring] certainly meets those criteria.

Comment: @BenVoigt What evidence backs up that statement?  ([tag:maintainabiliy] is not a meta tag)

Comment: @Mogsdad: The meaning of "meta"?  [tag:maintainability] is after all, a property of the code, not the greater context where the developer encountered that code.  meta tags like [tag:homework] or [tag:code-maintenance] describe that greater context, not the code itself, which is what makes them meta.

Comment: @BenVoigt Would you defend [readability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readability)? These are not good tags: they tend to attract opinion-based answers. You say they describe the code, that doesn't mean they describe the content of the question. You're using the dictionary definition of meta, not [the SO definition](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: I didn't say it was a good tag, I said it was not a meta tag. Meta and bad are not synonymous.

Comment: BTW the three tags in that blog post are metatags. The rest of the post, is just wrong. Ambiguous and meta are not synonyms either. If you want an accepted definition, better point to a meta question that was voted on, not a blog post that represents one non-expert opinion.

Answer (score 3):

After at least five years [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) has only one follower, which I take as a sign it is not of much use, of which further signs are no usage guidance and no wiki.

Excluding deleted posts, it is presently applied 13 times, once on a closed question.

Only for one of the open questions is it the only tag:

[If it ain't broke don't fix or upgrade it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616833/if-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-or-upgrade-it)

This seems to be very much a matter of opinion (that there are 11 answers is some indication of that) so I have VTC’d it.

That leaves 11 questions:

[How to update old C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007707/how-to-update-old-c-code)

Question is more than 5 years old and again seems to, now, be off topic as too much a matter of opinion (11 answers). One of which (+19) is:

> This shoehorning into C++ seems to be arbitrary, ask your boss why he needs that done, figure out if you can meet the same goal less painfully, see if you can prototype a subset in the new less painful way, then go and demo to your boss and recommend that you follow the less painful way.

[How to determine if an existing class can be unit-tested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796063/how-to-determine-if-an-existing-class-can-be-unit-tested)

Questions are:

> Is there any good article you recommend on guidelines which help to identify classes which are easier to unit-test?

and

> Do you have any advice of your own?

So IMO now off topic on two counts (‘recommendations’ and ‘opinion’).

[Matching ASP.NET source code to a compiled web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121674/matching-asp-net-source-code-to-a-compiled-web-application)

Question is:

> Is there any way to determine which (if any) of those versions is the one actually deployed to the production web site?

IMO does not require [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) (has three others).

[maintain MPI version and non MPI version in a convenient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368891/maintain-mpi-version-and-non-mpi-version-in-a-convenient-way)

Seems to me [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) may be appropriate here. However already tagged [parallel-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parallel-processing)[mpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpi) which would seem adequate.

[From Visual Studio projects to CMake projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097821/from-visual-studio-projects-to-cmake-projects)

Has a Comment:

> possible duplicate of vcxproj to cmake

which links to a similar question which is *not* tagged [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code).

[Provide version to independent files in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467305/provide-version-to-independent-files-in-clearcase)

Already tagged [clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clearcase) (and [config-spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/config-spec)) [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) seems to me to add nothing of value.

[GWT Modify file on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442145/gwt-modify-file-on-server)

Seems to me [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) may be appropriate here. However already tagged [gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt)[web-deployment-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-deployment-project) which would seem adequate.

[Fragments seems to be overkill? No MVC architecture possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859241/fragments-seems-to-be-overkill-no-mvc-architecture-possible)

Question is:

> Whats your opinion and advice about fragments?

Three answers, including one from OP. This might not be as much a matter of opinion as first appears but other existing tags: [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller)[design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns)[android-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragments) would seem fully adequate.

[Compact or renumber IDs for all tables, and reset sequences to max(id)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894162/compact-or-renumber-ids-for-all-tables-and-reset-sequences-to-maxid)

Verging on off topic for including:

> Or is there any plugin or maintaining utility for this job?

The question is at least as much about renumbering IDs in a database as anything of a code maintenance nature. IMO [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) should be removed as more misleading than helpful.

[How to maintain different portlet codebases for Liferay 6.0 and 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631703/how-to-maintain-different-portlet-codebases-for-liferay-6-0-and-6-1)

Seems to me [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) may be appropriate here. However already tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)[liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay)[backwards-compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backwards-compatibility) which would seem adequate and [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) perhaps more misleading than helpful.

[Syntax error in complex macro expansion for some, but not all compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252344/syntax-error-in-complex-macro-expansion-for-some-but-not-all-compilers)

A question asked over three years ago with requests for clarification from that time that have not been respected with responses. OP has seemingly not revisited for over three years. 163 views and net `-1`, this question should IMO be deleted.

So there may be some argument for [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code) being of some relevance to two or three questions but out of over 10M and since not concerning a new technology (hence unlikely to be required, if at all, much more frequently in the near term) it is better to kill it off now than to preserve it and write the usage guidance and wiki for it.

Note I am not addressing the other tags in this OP in view of (i) a dim recollection of some advice that each burnination request should focus on a single tag (though I believe that was with the caveat of the kind “or a closely related group of tags”) and (ii) trying to justify removing 12 tags is more than tedious enough.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis of each of the remaining questions!

Comment: [The tag has been *burninated*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm85C.png)